# Retrieving full address and geocoding based on place/store name and city stored in csv

Tags: python, csv, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, nominatim

I have a csv file with 2 fields, `store_name` and `city`. There can be multiple stores in a city.
I want an output csv with 5 fields, `store_name`, `city`, `address`, `latitude`, `longitude`.

For example, if one entry of the csv is `Starbucks, Chicago`, I want the output csv to contain all the information in the 5 fields (mentioned above) as:
`Starbucks, Chicago, "200 S Michigan Ave, Chicago, IL 60604, USA", 41.8164613, -87.8127855`,
 `Starbucks, Chicago, "8 N Michigan Ave, Chicago, IL 60602, USA", 41.8164613, -87.8127855`
and so on for the rest of the results.

I was trying to work this through GeoPy using Nomanitim, before making it work with Google Maps API. Although I do not know what is the best way to approach this. Do note that there are a million of such entries in the source csv, but buying an API key is not an issue once it works.

I did try only geocoding with Nominatim using pandas, but this only creates one result in the output csv for each entry. I want to grab each result as explained in the example above. Not sure how to implement it.

```py
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import csv, sys
import pandas as pd
import keys

in_file = str(sys.argv[1])
out_file = str('gc_' + in_file)
timeout = int(sys.argv[2])

nominatim = Nominatim(user_agent=your_key_here, timeout=timeout)

def gc(address):
    name = str(address['store_name'])
    city = str(address['city'])
    add_concat = name + ", " + city
    location = nominatim.geocode(add_concat)
    if location != None:
        print(f'geocoded record {address.name}: {city}')
        located = pd.Series({
            'lat': location.latitude,
            'lng': location.longitude,
        })
    else:
        print(f'failed to geolocate record {address.name}: {city}')
        located = pd.Series({
            'lat': 'null',
            'lng': 'null',
        })
    return located

print('opening input.')
reader = pd.read_csv(in_file, header=0)
print('geocoding addresses.')
reader = reader.merge(reader.apply(lambda add: gc(add), axis=1), left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(f'writing to {out_file}.')
reader.to_csv(out_file, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
print('done.')
```

Comment: best way? have you tried using the 2 ways you mentioned above?

Comment: You can't. A query like "Starbucks Chicago" is not sufficient for returning all the addresses of Starbucks from a geocoding/reverse geocoding engine.

Comment: +Ervin Ruci You are right. What I am trying to implement now is using the python client for google maps, and [Find Place Request](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#FindPlaceRequests) of Places API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reverse geocoding` for that purpose. As per the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start), it's a way of converting geographic coordinates into a human-readable address.

I used the below function in one of my projects and it's still working. You can probably modify it as per your requirements.

```
import requests

GCODE_URL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'
GCODE_KEY = 'YOUR API KEY' 

def reverse_gcode(location):
    location = str(location).replace(' ','+')
    nav_req = 'address={}&key={}'.format(location,GCODE_KEY)
    request = GCODE_URL + nav_req
    result = requests.get(request)
    data = result.json()
    status = data['status']

    geo_location = {}
    if str(status) == "OK":
       sizeofjson = len(data['results'][0]['address_components'])
       for i in range(sizeofjson):
           sizeoftype = len(data['results'][0]['address_components'][i]['types'])
           if sizeoftype == 3:
              geo_location[data['results'][0]['address_components'][i]['types'][2]] = data['results'][0]['address_components'][i]['long_name']

           else:
              if data['results'][0]['address_components'][i]['types'][0] == 'administrative_area_level_1':
                 geo_location['state'] = data['results'][0]['address_components'][i]['long_name']

              elif data['results'][0]['address_components'][i]['types'][0] == 'administrative_area_level_2':
                   geo_location['city'] = data['results'][0]['address_components'][i]['long_name']
                   geo_location['town'] = geo_location['city']

               else:
                   geo_location[data['results'][0]['address_components'][i]['types'][0] ]= data['results'][0]['address_components'][i]['long_name']

       formatted_address = data['results'][0]['formatted_address']
       geo_location['lat'] = data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
       geo_location['lang']= data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
       geo_location['formatted_address']=formatted_address

       return geo_location

print(reverse_gcode("Starbucks, Chicago"))
```

Output will be in a `json` format, looks something like this:

```
{'street_number': '8', 'town': 'Cook County', 'locality': 'Chicago', 'city': 'Cook County', 'lat': 41.882413, 'neighborhood': 'Chicago Loop', 'route': 'North Michigan Avenue', 'lang': -87.62468799999999, 'postal_code': '60602', 'country': 'United States', 'formatted_address': '8 N Michigan Ave, Chicago, IL 60602, USA', 'state': 'Illinois'}
```